# can we convert nested list to xml using some jquery property?

Tags: c#, jquery, xml

I have JSON data which binds html nested list.I want to convert this list into XML format. Is there any property which gives xml.
Like we use .ToString() do we have same.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Updated answer please let me know for more...

```
$('#go').click(function() {
    var xml = '<List>';
     $("ul#list li").each(function(){
      var name = $(this).children('.name-block').text();
      var value = $(this).children(".value-block").text();
      if(name && value){
        xml += "<Item>\n";
        xml += "<Name>" + name + "</Name>\n";
        xml += "<Value>" + value + "</Value>\n";
        xml += "</Item>\n";
      }
    });
    xml += "</list>"
    $('.modal-body').append(xml);
    $("#myModal").modal('show');
    console.log(xml)
    })
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-sm-offset-6 col-sm-3">
        <button type="button" id="go" class="btn btn-primary">Open XML Modal Box</button>
      </div>
    </div>
<!--Modal if input is empty-->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>

        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">you xml value printed below</h4>

      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>

    <ul id="list">
                <li>
                    <span class="name name-block">Hello</span><span>=</span><span class="name value-block">World</span>
                    <span class="btn delete">Delete</span>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <span class="name name-block">Happy</span><span>=</span><span class="name value-block">Coding</span>
                    <span class="btn delete">Delete</span>
                </li>
            </ul>

    <!-- /.modal -->
    <!--End Modal-->
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thanks. Consider a scenario. There is a nested list(html list) already.and without using any json data, just write an xml by using classname or id of <ol>